# Present ViewControllerB and dismiss ViewControllerA

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to dismiss ViewControllerA after I presented ViewControllerB

My current code for presenting ViewControllerB is :

```
 let viewControllerB = ViewControllerB()
 self.present(viewControllerB, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What i want to happen is that when ViewControllerB is loaded to dismiss ViewControllerA

I tried using a delegate so that ViewControllerB could notify ViewControllerA that it should be dismissed but what happens is that ViewControllerB is being dismissed:

Delegate and viewDidAppear() function in ViewControllerB:

```
protocol DismissDelegate : class {
    func dismissVC (_ dismiss: Bool)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        delegate?.dismissVC(true)
    }
```

and the callback in ViewControllerA

```
func dismissVC(_ dismiss: Bool) {
        print("dismissVC delegate")
        ViewControllerA().dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

I am not using storyboards in my application if that makes any difference.

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong or not doing at all?

Comment: Who presented A?

Comment: another view controller. The flow is MainMenu -> ViewControllerA -> ViewControllerB. And as soon as ViewControllerB is presented i want to dismiss ViewControllerB hence from ViewControllerB i will be going to MainMenu

Comment: In this code: `SignInVC().dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)` you are creating a ***new instance*** of `SignInVC`. Where is `dismissVC()` actually located?

Comment: I edited my question according to my answer to make more sense with the ViewControllers

Comment: Not sure the concept would work MainMenu -> nil (dismissed) -> ViewControllerB

Comment: On viewcontrollers-B dismiss Do you want to dismiss 2 view controllers (B and A) from viewcontrollers-B and go back to menu controllers ?

Comment: @SidMhatre no. On viewcontrollers-B dismiss i only want ViewcontrollerA to be dismissed.

Comment: On viewcontrollers-B dismiss you want ViewcontrollerA to be dismissed then which will be current viewController ? and in stack there will be Menu -> A -> B controller right ?

Comment: For first question the current viewController will be Menu. and for second question the stack is Menu-> A->B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are presenting `viewControllerB` from `viewControllerA`. You cannot dismiss `viewControllerA` without also dismissing `viewControllerB`, because it `viewControllerA` is presenting view controller of `viewControllerB`.

You will have to first dismiss `viewControllerA` and in completion block then present `viewControllerB`, so try this:

```
let customerMenu = CustomerMenuVC()
// this should dismiss current view controller
let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController!
self.dismiss(animated: false) {
    presentingVC.present(customerMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This just dismissed ViewControllerA nothing else

Comment: @pavlos I fixed it, try it now

Comment: Same results. dismissed ViewControllerA

Comment: @pavlos how about now?